# Is there someway to convert a python stack frame into a unique number to use as a key to some container?

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection, scoping

Consider the following sample of code:

```py
import random

def inner(self):
    frame_info = inspect.stack()[1]
    value = random.uniform(0, 1)
```

I would like to convert `frame_info` into a dictionary key.

After that, I would like to store `value` in the dictionary at the key value computed from `frame_info`

Something like:

```py
dictionary[hash(frame_info)] = value
```

We have the following information about the object named `frame_info`:

```
frame_info           is instantiated from <class 'inspect.FrameInfo'>
frame_info.code_context         <class 'list'> ['    inner()\\n']
frame_info.count                <class 'builtin_function_or_method'> <built-in method count of FrameInfo object at 0x00000217915791E0>
frame_info.filename             <class 'str'> C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\library_whose_values_have_context.py
frame_info.frame                <class 'frame'> <frame at 0x0000021791494550, file 'C:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\PycharmProjects\\\\pythonProject\\\\library_whose_values_have_context.py', line 91, code foo>
frame_info.function             <class 'str'> foo
frame_info.index                <class 'int'> 0
frame_info.lineno               <class 'int'> 91
```

I am hoping that some of the stuff above (attributes of `frame_info`) are useful for generating dictionary keys unique to a particular function call.

The idea is to store a random number in a dictionary every time we call a function where the key associated with the random number is a unique immutable object belonging to that function (or maybe the function call instead of the function itself).

```py
import random

class Klass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._d = dict()

    def inner(self):
        frame_info = inspect.stack()[1]
        key = str(frame_info)
        self._d[key] = random.uniform(0, 1)

obj = Klass()

foo = lambda *args : obj.inner()
bar = lambda *args : obj.inner()
baz = lambda *args : obj.inner()

foo()
bar()
baz()

print(obj._d)
```

In case it helps to know, I do not particularly care about random numbers.

What I really want to do is have a member variable of an custom-made object obey scoping rules as if it was a local variable inside of a function.

For example, I want `obj.myVar = 244` to behave like `myVar = 244` in the sense that `obj.myVar` could have different values inside of different function calls.

Also `obj.myVar` should get pushed onto a stack, and popped off that stack (if necessary) in order to obey the usual rules associated with nested function calls.

Comment: Hint: hash functions

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski python has a built-in function `hash`. It would not surprise me if there is a method named `__hash__` defined somewhere inside of the class `inspect.FrameInfo`. However, the last time I posted a question about `__hash__` on stackoverflow, a lot of people commented that many different objects can map to the same hash value. Everyone insisted that hash-table collisions are normal and that `hash(x) == hash(y)` does not mean that `x == y` That other question about hasing was down-voted and deleted.

Comment: Hash collision can happen but if you i.e. would hash the whole stacktrace (or stacktrace as string) then it most likely should be sufficiently unique to not bite you here.